# Behavior of IBM Bluemix Swift Object Storage "X-Newest" flag

Tags: ibm-cloud, openstack-swift, object-storage

I am using the IBM Cloud Object Storage with Swift API on IBM Bluemix as seen here https://console.bluemix.net/catalog/infrastructure/object-storage-group.

I need to get the newest version of an object, or to know if it was deleted. To do so I use the `X-Newest` header flag in the request, but still I can get an object that was already deleted. Is there a known problem with this flag? Is it supported by the storage service? If it is, can you help to investigate why it happens?

Problematic scenario (Swift local client):

1. add an object
2. delete this object
3. pull this object (Get or Head) with `X-Newest` flag

and expect always to get "Object Not found" `404` status code (because it was deleted in the previous step). But in reality, sometimes I get this object back although it was deleted. Swift is eventually consistent, and without this flag, it would be a normal behavior. But with this flag, I should not get old versions of the object.

Do you know why it happens?

Comment: Could you post the code your are executing?